# RTL side navigation tailwindcss alpinejs

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

Does anyone know how to build a 'RTL side navigation tailwindcss alpinejs' in TailwindCSS /AlpineJS?

I found a great example of what I want. [This Code in github](https://github.com/ThirusOfficial/side-navigation-tailwindcss-alpinejs/tree/main/layouts)

But this is a left-to-right example, and I could not make it right to left.

please guide me

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to set the dir attribute to rtl  inside the html tag